# When didving by 0, I want it to print given text

Tags: python, if-statement, math, printing, error-handling

```
import math

def roots4(outfile,a,b,c):
    """Prints the solutions of 'x' for equation ax² + bx + c = 0 """
    d = b * b - 4 * a * c
    if a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 0:
        print "X = All complex/real numbers."

    if c != 0:
        print "X = No real solutions."

    e = (-c / (b))
    if a == 0 and b > 0 < c:
        print "There's only one solution: " + e

    solutions = [str(-b / (2 * a))]
    if a != 0 and d == 0:
        print "There's only one solution: " + solutions 

    solutions2 = [str((-b + math.sqrt(d)) / 2.0 / a), str((-b - math.sqrt(d)) / 2.0 / a)]
    if a != 0 and d > 0:
        print "There's two solutions: " + solutions2

    xre = str((-b) / (2 * a))
    xim = str((math.sqrt(-d)) / (2 * a))
    solutions3 = [xre + " + " + xim +"i", xre + " - " + xim +"i"]
    if a != 0 and d < 0:
        print "Solutions are: " + solutions3
```

I get a "ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero" error because I'm dividing by zero when "b" is "0" from an input file. How can I bypass the error so it can print the desired text? My desired output needs to be the desired print statement when meeting the "if" conditions.

where (a, b, c)

```
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0

    0.0, 0.0, 1.0

    0.0, 2.0, 4.0

    1.0, 2.0, 1.0

    1.0, -5.0, 6.0

    1.0, 2.0, 3.0
```

Comment: Just... don't divide by zero? Why do you even have a division with a denominator that could be zero here?

Comment: You're not even *using* `e`!

Comment: I'm solving for x in the equation  "ax² + bx + c = 0". So, when a,b,c equal 0, x can be "All complex numbers" Unless, you can think of another way to go around the error, I'm open for it.

Comment: Oops, sorry mistyped the code. "e" is used in the third if statement

Comment: Your docstring says `a != 0`. It is an error to feed this function an input with `a == 0`. Your math is outright wrong in many places (all 3 of the first `if` clauses jump out as mathematically wrong), you're trying to add strings to lists, and you're trying to perform calculations in cases when they're not defined and not needed. Why are you trying to perform solution calculations for cases that don't apply to the given input?

Comment: What I posted is part of a larger file, where I'm required to input a,b,c from another file and output the solutions into another file. I'm solving for "x" In the case where a,b,c = 0.0,0.0,0.0 , x can be any real/complex number because I'll still get 0. In the case where, a,b,c = 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 , x has no real solution because when solving the equation (0.0)x^2 + (0.0)x + (1) = 0, 1 does not 0. Therefore, X has no real solutions. I don't know if I'm making any sense.

Comment: Your code and your posts are saying completely different things. For example, your post is saying that a=b=c=0 gives all complex numbers as solutions (correct), but your code is checking for `d == 0 and b == 0`.

Comment: I'm editing hoping it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the Python. But know the concept.

So please rectify the Python code error.

**Prints the solutions of ax² + bx + c = 0**

```
def roots4(outfile,a,b,c):
d = (b * b) - (4 * a * c)    


if a == 0 and b == 0 and c==0:
   print "This is not quadratic equations"
if a == 0 and b == 0:
   print "Invalid equations"
if a == 0:
   e = [str(-b / (2 * a))]
   print "There's only one solution: X=" + e        
if d == 0 :
   solutions = -b / (2 * a)
   print "Two roots are same X = " + solutions
if d > 0:
   solutions2 = [str((-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a)), str((-b - math.sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a))]
   print "There's two solutions: " + solutions2
if d < 0:
   xre = str((-b) / (2 * a))
   xim = str((math.sqrt(-d)) / (2 * a))
   solutions3 = [xre + " + " + xim +"i", xre + " - " + xim +"i"]
   print "Solutions are: " + solutions3
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess you can look at it that way. It has to work with the given (a,b,c) that I provided above.     (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

    (0.0, 2.0, 4.0)

    (1.0, 2.0, 1.0)

    (1.0, -5.0, 6.0)

    (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)

Comment: @JesusAnaya Thanks.. Welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this? Can you not think of a better way to display text? How about you don't divide by zero at all? Try displaying results without dividing by only dividing if *not* dividing by zero.